# Proper display of footer elements in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am having trouble positioning the image in my footer on Mobile screen size. It looks great in browser, but the image is cut off on the bottom in mobile, and the Copyright is above the image with the badges.

Here is the css I used in the custom html block in the footer theme customization settings:

```
    <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0449/8210/8310/files/Sacred-Footer-layout-icons.jpg?v=1611374743" 
  style="position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0px;">
</div>
<div style="text-align: center !important;">
     <small>
    © 2021 Sacred Coffee Co.
    </small>
</div>
```

[image: Desktop view - this looks good]

[image: Mobile view - image cut off & copyright above image]

And here is my site url https://sacredcoffeeco.com.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the code, and make changes if there is any conflict with existing  CSS.

```
@media screen and ( max-width:749px ){
   /* hide the last line and hr */
   footer .page-width:last-child,.site-footer__hr {
      display: none;
   }
   .site-footer__content {
      height: auto;padding: 0;
   }
   .site-footer__item-inner.site-footer__item-inner--html_content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
   }
   .site-footer__item-inner.site-footer__item-inner--html_content div:first-child {
      order: 1;
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css properties for the img tag

```
img{
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
 }
```